# Redirect Ongoing Python Console Output to File

Tags: python, subprocess, ascii, stdout, executable

I'm trying to run an ASCII game (specifically Rogue) and save the console's output consistently to a text file. So far I managed to make these two scripts:

```
import subprocess
with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    subprocess.run("ROGUE.EXE", stdout=file)
```

```
import subprocess
import tempfile
with open("output.txt", 'w') as out:
    process = subprocess.Popen("ROGUE.EXE", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout = process.communicate()[0]
    print('STDOUT:{}'.format(stdout))
```

They both work to an extent but it requires the executable to be terminated before saving the output to a file. I need this to happen between intervals *while* the executable is running.

Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/74127/tee-for-windows

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already had used TEE while using something like:
`./ROGUE.EXE | tee -filepath POP.TXT`
It works to a degree, but it stops at some point for some reason. Might be related to how the game output's work. However the game's output still is a terminal with, say, copy-pastable characters. So I'm assuming there has to be a way to make it work.